# Better way to replace timestamp by date when reading a squid log

Tags: bash, awk, date, squid

Tonight i was trying to look at my proxie's lines, and I came up with this, which seems all but KISS. How would you do it simply ?

```
 awk '{ trunc=sprintf("%.0f", $1) ;$1="" ; system("echo -n `date +%R -d\"@" trunc "\" `") ; print $0 ;}' </var/log/squid3/access.log
```

Lines in there begin with : `137816847.548` (hence the space delimiting next field, number totally random here)

Comment: How about an example of a full log line and what you're hoping for as output?  Looks like change the timestamp to a human readable date, and output the whole line?

Comment: See @justbrowsing answer for an example of a line, thought the only significant part is the first field. What i want is indeed to be able to replace this field which is an UTC timestamp(with millisec) into a human readable date with choosable format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small python script that should be quite robust and easily extended:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os
from datetime import datetime

try:
    if not os.path.isfile(sys.argv[1]):
        sys.stderr.write("[Error]: %s is not a file\n" % sys.argv[1])
        sys.exit(1)
except IndexError:
    sys.stderr.write("Usage: parse_squid_log.py access.log\n")
    sys.exit(1)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as log:
    for line in log:
        line = line.split(' ')
        line[0] = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(float(line[0])))
        print ' '.join(line).strip()
```

Save it to a file such a `parse_squid_log` and make sure it's executable `chmod +x parse_squid_log` and on your `path`.

**Usage:**

```
$ parse_squid_log
Usage: parse_squid_log.py access.log

$ parse_squid_log abc
[Error]: abc is not a file

$ parse_squid_log /var/log/squid3/access.log
2013-07-23 05:19:26.136000      929 185.168.101.131 TCP_MISS/200 28198 ...
2013-07-23 05:23:07.488000      0 10.42.0.14 TCP_IMS_HIT/304 278 GET ...
2014-05-08 13:49:47.488000      0 10.42.0.14 TCP_IMS_HIT/304 278 GET ...
```

Comment: I could have done this in Perl, but I had tried to be simple. After all your solution is what should be done by anyone in this need.

Answer (score 2):

With cat pipe perl:

```
cat access.log | perl -p -e 's/^([0-9]*)/"[".localtime($1)."]"/e'
```

or pure perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\d+/localtime($&)/e' access.log
```

Comment: As a fellow perl-nut, I do like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the logfile is something like this:

```
1374553166.136    929 185.168.101.131 TCP_MISS/200 28198 GET http://www.amazon.de/gp/offer-listing/B000NOIW62/ref=sr_1_1_olp? - DIRECT/178.236.7.219 text/html
1374553387.488      0 10.42.0.14 TCP_IMS_HIT/304 278 GET http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/da/creatives/sn130.png - NONE/- image/png
1399553387.488      0 10.42.0.14 TCP_IMS_HIT/304 278 GET http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/da/creatives/sn130.png - NONE/- image/png
```

`awk '{ cmd = ("date +%R -d @"$1); cmd | getline timestamp; close(cmd); $1=""; print timestamp$0 }' /var/log/squid3/access.log`

Command breakdown:

- `date` command set to convert epoch time to 24-hour hour and minute
- set variable `cmd` to desired date command
- execute cmd and pipe into variable `timestamp`
- `close` system output
- set column 1 to blank (to prevent duplication)
- print converted time and the rest of the columns

OR

Better yet with only awk:

`awk '{timestamp=strftime("%R",$1); $1=""; print timestamp$0}' /var/log/squid3/access.log`

Comment: Indeed your solution seems to be better awk than mine, especially the latter. I'll keep the question unanswered for a week to see if someone comes up with a sexier, non-`awk`solution. If not, i'll take yours. +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

Add logformat squid with parameters to /etc/squid/squid.conf, see [man page](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/logformat/).

For example I use:

```
logformat squid %tl IP:%>a %ru err_code
```

Important is %tl, which mean, make timestamp in local time.

Comment: This is another way to reach my goal. It's the simpliest, but will only work with newer logs. One would have to convert old logs to the new date format with one of the above methods.